# What may be called a big spot on the top of the head of an aged man?

Tags: word-request

Here's a photo of an aged man:
[image: 1]

And here's another one when he was younger:
[image: 2]

What's the English for the spot on the crown of his head? It's too big and quite unusual in shape to be called a mole, isn't it? May it just be  called  a pigmented spot or there's a more exact and interesting word for it? And the man wasn't born with it and he didn't have it when he was a few decades younger than in the photo.

[image: 3]

And here, he is yet much younger:

[image: 4]

Comment: Hmmm. I suspect that the nevus (flammeus or vascularis, take your pick) was always there, but that some apparatchik in the Commissariat of People's Images decided to apply a little airbrushery. There was a grand tradition of such hijinks—remember the "Vanishing Commissar" Nikolai Yezhov?

Comment: @P.E.Dant - You made me laugh remembering the Naked Gun episode where Lesley Nilson during the fist fight rubbed his head top and the spot dissappeared, Lesley exclaimimg something like "So I knew!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a

> [port-wine stain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port-wine_stain) *(nevus flammeus)*
>   firemark

of which Mr Gorbachev has an excellent example.

Comment: And a firemark?

Comment: Yes, *firemark* is also cited in the Wiki link

Comment: _Strawberry birthmark,_ is a useful term also, or just _Strawberry mark,_

Comment: I always associated a strawberry mark with girls for some reason. I knew one, even had red hair, she said the story was her Mom ate a lot of strawberries when pregnant.